# TYPO3: tt_news multilanguage configuration - [more] link shown despite there is no translation

Tags: configuration, typo3, multilingual, tt-news

What has to be done to have News in another language than the default language available. I already have:

- Website Language
- Page translation for news overview (Displaying: LATEST)
- Page translation for detailed news (Displaying: SINGLE)

In my default language everything is working. But for the new language I only see empty News on the page with a [more] link which gives me `no news_id given` when clicked. Do I have to create a page translation for the folder in which the news are stored? Up to now I only can set the language for each news entry.

**Edit:**

I created a translation for my folder, which stores the news. Now it seems to work. But how can I remove the [more] link if there is no translation?

This is in the HTML code

```
<div class="news-latest-container">

          <div class="news-latest-item">
            <div class="news-item-left"><a title="" href="xxx/news/news-detail.html"></a></div>
            <div class="news-item-right">
                <h3><a title="" href="xxx/news/news-detail.html"></a></h3>
                <p></p><hr class="clearer">

                <div class="news-latest-morelink"><a title="" href="xxx/news/news-detail.html">[more]</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="news-latest-item">
            <div class="news-item-left"><a title="" href="xxx/news/news-detail.html"></a></div>
            <div class="news-item-right">
                <h3><a title="" href="xxx/news/news-detail.html"></a></h3>
                <p></p><hr class="clearer">

                <div class="news-latest-morelink"><a title="" href="xxx/news/news-detail.html">[more]</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>


</div>
```

I also used

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList.subheader_stdWrap.append >
```

to supress the second more link. But why are there empty news displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a translation for my folder, which stores the news. Now it seems to work. For the other question: I added the following lines of code:

```
plugin.tt_news.showNewsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 0
plugin.tt_news.sys_language_mode = strict
```

Now `no news in this list.` is displayed.